# Xamarin issues with Fody.WeavingTask and SolutionDir

Tags: xamarin, realm, fody

I have been trying to use Realm in my Xamarin android proyect, one of it's dependencie is Fody, each time i try to run my app it shows the following error:
error MSB4044: The "Fody.WeavingTask" task was not given a value for the required parameter "SolutionDir".

I have been looking for a fix, but can't find it, do you know how to give it a value? where is it?

For the realm nugget package i already created the FodyWeavers.xml

Comment: Are you building via VSTS, some other CI server, cmd-line or directly in Visual Studio (Windows or Mac)?

Answer (score 61):

uff, that's a bug
you just need to close the solution and open it again.

Comment: These are those kinds of Xamarin issues that makes me want to break my keyboard in half. Thank you.

Comment: I agree this is very frustrating but this may not be Xamarin-specific.  I experienced this with a .NET console application.

Comment: I got bit by this too and the solution wasn't obvious. Wonder if this is reproducible... Would be great to be able to send a bug report to whoever could fix it.

Comment: This is specific to Fody, not Xamarin, I got a similar error ```Fody.weavingtask task was not given a value for the required parameter IntermediateDir``` and restarting the solution fixes the issue

Comment: In my case, it was "IntermediateDir" instead of "SolutionDir" and re-opening the solution did fix the problem.

Answer (score 7):

Haahh.., I resolved the same issue by just restarting my `solution`. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about the error you are getting. Please check for the following points:

1.The FodyWeavers.xml should be in all projects in your solution and looks like this

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Weavers>
   <RealmWeaver/>
</Weavers>
```

2.As of today the latest realm package ver 3.0.0 is compatible with Fody ver 2.5.0.

Comment: I created the FodyWeavers for all projects, my problem was bug.